# SSRS: Determining a Monthly Date Excluding Weekends

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report that will generate a monthly date depending on the reporting month selected.  The due date is the 20th of the month, unless that date falls on a weekend or holiday.  I may be able to exclude the holidays but how do I write an expression to pull this?

Parameters would be reporting month, as an integer, and reporting year.

The person who created the report before me in Crystal used this formula:

if DayofWeek({@Apr Due Date}) = 1 then  {@Apr Due Date} + 1  else
if DayofWeek({@Apr Due Date}) = 7 then ({@Apr Due Date} + 2) else {@Apr Due Date}

But I was trying to see if there was a way to do one expression to cover any month entered in the parameter.

I am using Report Builder 3.0 and tsql.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your system first day of week is `Sunday` and last day is Saturday as it seems in your Crystal Report expression.

You have two parameters:

```
Year  - Integer
Month - Integer
```

The due date is always 20 day of month.

Create an additional parameter called `NoHolidayDueDate` and set it to `Hidden`. Use the below expression for the `Default Value` property.

This should apply that logic in a SSRS expression.

```
=Switch(
DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Month.Value,20).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday,
DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Month.Value,22),
DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Month.Value,20).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday,
DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Month.Value,21),
true,DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Month.Value,20)
)
```

Then in your query use the `NoHolidayDueDate` something like this:

```
WHERE [Date] < @NoHolidayDueDate
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(dateadd(day,20 - day(getdate()),getdate()) as date)
```

to get 20 non-weekend days in

```
DECLARE @DAY_IN_MONTH DATE = '2016-09-09';   --any date in any month


WITH DS AS (SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@DAY_IN_MONTH),@DAY_IN_MONTH) AS DAY20
            UNION ALL
            SELECT dateadd(day,1,DAY20) FROM DS WHERE DAY(DAY20) < 31),
    DS2 AS (SELECT *,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DAY20) RN FROM DS WHERE  LEFT(DATENAME(dw,DAY20),3) NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN'))
    SELECT DAY20 FROM DS2 WHERE rn = 20;
```

Comment: hold on, do you mean 20 business days into the month?  You need a table with working days of the month in it, then you need to select the days with row_number() OVER (ORDER BY TheDate) , then you need to select the one with row_number = 20

Comment: Yes, 20 business days into each month, sorry for the confusion.  That's what I was afraid of.  I had seen that on several posts.

Comment: or do you mean the first day of the month, on or after the 20th, which is not a weekend?  Because that is what the formula you posted seems to do already.